# Why does the FreeBSD kernal crash on UEFI boot?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, uefi, freebsd

I recently downloaded the FreeBSD 10.2 distribution from the official website; I used the '[FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64-uefi-memstick.img.xz](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/10.2/)' file. I used MS ImageWriter to image a USB and proceeded to UEFI boot the stick. Apparently, the stick does boot and the kernel starts. Shortly, however, it faults and reports the following error message:

```
kernel trap 12 with interrupts disabled

Fatal trap 12: page fault while in kernel mode
cpuid = 0; apic id = 00
fault virtual address   = 0xd5
fault code              = supervisor read data, page not present
instruction pointer     = 0x20:0xffffffff80bcf206
stack pointer           = 0x28:0xffffffff814f1d70
frame pointer           = 0x28:0xffffffff814f1df0
code segment            = base 0x0, limit 0xfffff, type 0x1b
                        = DPL 0, pres 1, long 1, def32 0, gran 1
processor eflags        = interrupt enabled, resume, IOPL = 0
current process         = 0 ()
trap number             = 12
panic: page fault
cpuid = 0
KDB: stack backtrace:
#0      0xffffffff80984e30 at ??+0
#1      0xffffffff809489e6 at ??+0
#2      0xffffffff809488b3 at ??+0
#3      0xffffffff80d4aadb at ??+0
#4      0xffffffff80d4addd at ??+0
#5      0xffffffff80d4a47a at ??+0
#6      0xffffffff80d307f2 at ??+0
#7      0xffffffff80bc2d80 at ??+0
#8      0xffffffff80bc2c57 at ??+0
#9      0xffffffff80d4ac8c at ??+0
#10     0xffffffff80d4a47a at ??+0
#11     0xffffffff80d307f2 at ??+0
Uptime: 1s
```

This error message does not change from boot to boot. I know UEFI support is new, but it shouldn't be broken. What is happening to the kernel? How severe and widespread is this error?

Notes:

I typed out the error message: It may contain typos.

The USB boots properly in CSM mode, and I can install FreeBSD from there, in BIOS format presumably.

I am using a Toshiba Satellite computer, recently purchased. The only hardware that I have noticed having no default FreeBSD driver is the RealTek network card.

Comment: in all likelihood, you will not be able to fix this, without replacing some thing, be it software or firmware. The message is saying that root tried to read a page of ram, and found there was nothing at that address. Many people tie this to firmware, so consider updating your firmware if the vendor has supplied any newer versions. Some people here are discussing the same issue: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/fatal-trap-12-page-fault-while-in-kernel-mode.26710/